# how to make polymer iron-list keep expanding, instead of scolling

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am following the example of [collapsible items of iron-list](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-list/demo/collapse.html). However, I have more content under the iron-list, say an iron-menu.

The issue is that the height of the iron-list does not dynamically increase as the user expand the iron-list contents. Instead the iron-list becomes scollable, making it hard to see all the contents.

I would like the iron-list to expand in height, and push down the content (iron-menu) below. Is there a way to do this? Many thanks.

I also tried to set the `scroll-target`, but it doesn't push the content below down. It overlaps the iron-list content onto the content below, which is not what I want.

```
<iron-list scroll-target="document" ... >
```

Comment: I think you're searching something like [this](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/iron-list/demo/scroll-threshold.html). Isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly. I still want to use collapsible items. The issue is that the total height of the iron-list seems to be fixed when it is created. When I expand the collapsed content, the length of the iron-list does not increase, instead it become scollable.

Comment: do you have a fiddle with your setup available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution. As you can see from [the example](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/demo/collapse.html), the function `getClassForItem()` changes the div class to control show/hide. Thus we can trigger the resize event together with it.

```
    getClassForItem: function(item, selected) {
      this.querySelector('iron-list').fire('iron-resize'); // added line
      return selected ? 'item expanded' : 'item';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the iron-list must be set explicitly, as described on the iron-list project ReadMe under "Sizing iron-list".

So you could use javascript to change the height, based on other conditions.

The other way of putting something 'below' an iron-list is to compute whether you are on the last list item, and add in a custom row (i.e. pagination) as shown [here](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/dont-get-fooled-is-iron-list-really-a-drop-in-replacement-for-dom-repeat-5b257a6c1a0c)

But if you don't have a huge dataset, you could use dom-repeat, which will add nodes to the DOM, and therefore you could have your list expand.